# Typed Event system

Tags: typescript

Currently trying to implement a typed event system where I face the following issue:

```
enum Event {
  ItemCreated = "item-created",
  UserUpdated = "user-updated",
}

export interface Events {
  [Event.ItemCreated]: (item: string) => void;
  [Event.UserUpdated]: (user: number) => void;
}

export interface EventListener<TEvent extends keyof Events = keyof Events> {
  event: TEvent;
  handler: (...args: Parameters<Events[TEvent]>) => void;
}

const UserListener: EventListener = {
  event: Event.UserUpdated,
  handler: (handlerArgs) => {
    console.log(handlerArgs);
  },
};
```

Unfortunately, the type of `handlerArgs` is `string | User` - but I want it to be only  `User`. What am I missing here?

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/NB85gW) meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Yep, this should work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with

```
interface EventListener<TEvent extends keyof Events = keyof Events> {
  event: TEvent;
  handler: (...args: Parameters<Events[TEvent]>) => void;
}
```

is that when you refer to the type as `EventListener` with no type argument, the type argument is inferred as [the default](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-3.html#generic-parameter-defaults) `keyof Events`, which is a [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types).  Then both `event` and `handler` are written in terms of that union independently of each other.

Really you want `EventListener<TEvent>` to *distribute* over unions in `TEvent`, so that `EventListener<X | Y>` will be equivalent to `EventListener<X> | EventListener<Y>`.  And therefore `EventListener` (with no type argument) should itself be a union.  (And since [`interface` types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#interfaces) cannot be unions, you'll need to change it to a [`type` alias](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-aliases) instead.)

There are various ways to write this.  You could use a [distributive conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types) to force a union input to produce a union output:

```
type EventListener<TEvent extends keyof Events = keyof Events> = 
  TEvent extends any ? {
    event: TEvent;
    handler: (...args: Parameters<Events[TEvent]>) => void;
  } : never;

type E = EventListener
/* type E = {
    event: Event.ItemCreated;
    handler: (item: string) => void;
} | {
    event: Event.UserUpdated;
    handler: (user: number) => void;
} */
```

But it seems like you might not even need to ever specify the type argument, in which case you can just define `EventListener` as a specific union type.  If so, you can refactor to make it a *distributive object type* (as coined in [microsoft/TypeScript#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109)) where you [index into](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) to get the desired union.  Like this:

```
type EventListener = { [TEvent in keyof Events]: {
  event: TEvent,
  handler: (...args: Parameters<Events[TEvent]>) => void
} }[keyof Events];

/* type EventListener = {
    event: Event.ItemCreated;
    handler: (item: string) => void;
} | {
    event: Event.UserUpdated;
    handler: (user: number) => void;
} */
```

---

Either way, `EventListener` is now a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions) and the compiler will use `event` as a discriminant property to narrow the type of the `handler` property as desired:

```
const UserListener: EventListener = {
  event: Event.UserUpdated,
  handler: (handlerArgs) => {
    handlerArgs.toFixed(2); // okay
    console.log(handlerArgs);
  },
};
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAogbqALlA3gKClAko4EDCATsAIa4AmUAvFAEQCWuEAtAMbFnDm0A0GUAVQDOwQgIAO5TpRq0wIwszCTpvNAF80aYAA9xAe0LJ6IXIQBmJVsFgJTQ1PwDa8JADoceIqQoBdAFxQABSMeIFCiIQmAOYAlNQAfFBw+vTkANzOrqZuwqISUn6BQfKigeAQAEai8VRJKWmZmmgA9ABU2nqGyIgAnuI22YgAMvQRoKIAPAAqQ1C6uCDkDgDWwL365rZIDjRrG1tDQkk0s3bIC6DLUCQgvVAA-I6YwOeBZ0iZmAAWt+QANmVgm4QSRCNEhIEAApgkgQYBmISTI5OD6mXwJWr1VIZDRQcqvUSZNB9AawajbUyjcYgUStNpQUmDCnoTAvN6UxAeJjeaRfNm-JaAwjFUIQcKRGJY5I4ppQAA+zzZhNMgSGuQUBT5-B+f2FxVKIqgFWqhGlDVx6igbRaWk6BiMjP6g3O1MWohZUFRcxMUH2m05QgCSpViHeQz4uqFQKCILcYIh0Nh8MRyPOQm95wx5pxePUTn9h3TvmJ7SdZKGbomhBZOvmHPVngIHAo-KjAJjYolURAcUSMsaeMVrOVDfOGvyKlbdcFHaNJQU5Ugppzg6tNq0rH0IAiggUVdpRsrY3dNZoI9DavHeTEU64kags-1wSfogAguChNKR+3hR+IW4iD6AAYvQOhcEEABMsTpFALQtFA+grCQvR1luO76ICbj-Po0RBK+hD-l+-LqHw6jpEAA)